# Where to get the Ebay PaymentProfileID, ShippingProfileID and ReturnProfileID?

Tags: java, ebay-api

I'm trying out the ebay api. Everything works fine, but I can't list an item cause I don't know my:

- PaymentProfileID
- ShippingProfileID
- ReturnProfileID

how do I get those IDs ?

Here is the code sample:

```
  SellerProfilesType sellerProfile=new SellerProfilesType();

  //Set Payment ProfileId
  input = ConsoleUtil.readString("Enter your Seller Policy Payment ProfileId : ");
  SellerPaymentProfileType sellerPaymentProfile=new SellerPaymentProfileType();
  sellerPaymentProfile.setPaymentProfileID(Long.valueOf(input));
  sellerProfile.setSellerPaymentProfile(sellerPaymentProfile);

  //Set Shipping ProfileId
  SellerShippingProfileType sellerShippingProfile=new SellerShippingProfileType();
  input = ConsoleUtil.readString("Enter your Seller Policy Shipping ProfileId : ");
  sellerShippingProfile.setShippingProfileID(Long.valueOf(input));
  sellerProfile.setSellerShippingProfile(sellerShippingProfile);

  //Set Return Policy ProfileId
  SellerReturnProfileType sellerReturnProfile=new SellerReturnProfileType();
  input = ConsoleUtil.readString("Enter your Seller Policy Return ProfileId : ");
  sellerReturnProfile.setReturnProfileID(Long.valueOf(input));
  sellerProfile.setSellerReturnProfile(sellerReturnProfile);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*PaymentProfileID*, *ShippingProfileID* and *ReturnProfileID* refer to the seller's Business Policies. Each seller has the ability to create several policies in their eBay account and are a way of speeding up the listing process. There are three types of policy and a seller can create several of each type.

- **Payment**

  The payment methods that a seller will accept.
- **Shipping**

  The costs and services for both domestic and international shipping that a seller will use.
- **Return**

  The seller's return policy.

In the normal process of listing an item a seller would have to enter payment, shipping and returns information. Many sellers find that this information does not change much between each item and so they are simply entering duplicate information each time they list. To simplify the listing process a seller can create several Business Policies and enter the information there. The seller can then associate a policy with an item the next time they list. [More information can be found via eBay](http://pages.ebay.co.uk/help/sell/business-policies.html).

When listing an item via the API you can associate a item with a Business Policy by specifying the unique numerical ID of a policy. In order to obtain the ID's you will need to call the [getSellerProfiles](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/business-policies/CallRef/getSellerProfiles.html) operation found in the [Business Policies API](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/business-policies/Concepts/BusinessPoliciesAPIGuide.html). Parsing the output of this operation will give you the ID's of any Business Policy that a seller has created.

Comment: I have setup business policies, and can retrieve payment, returns and shipping policy id's. How do I revise an item to change the payment method to use the policy ID? I can't seem to find the correct $item->Property to change.

Answer (score 0):

You may not add **Business Policies API** to your app if you only want to get **PaymentProfileID, ShippingProfileID, ReturnProfileID**.

You can use this https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/default.aspx

Comment: Actually, there is no option for "Business Policies API" in the "API Explorer"